# pyenv deletes python after installing

Tags: python, linux, installation, raspberry-pi, pyenv

I try installing python with

```
pyenv install 3.11.0
```

(though this happens no matter the version) on my Raspberry Pi. When the install is running, there's a `3.11.0` directory in `~/.pyenv/versions`, `pyenv versions` recognizes it, and **the installed python is actually usable**, but the dir disappears after the installation process finished.

Raspberry Pi OS - Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) aarch64

Aside from one time when it errored out, this has happened every time I tried installing, including 3.11, 3.10, 3.9 and 3.8

I have tried:

- Installing `python` 3.11, 3.10, 3.9 and 3.8, so I dont think it will work with any other version
- Reinstalling `pyenv` and its dependencies multiple times

Comment: Is the process finished without errors? Did you `pyenv update` first just in case? Does `pyenv versions` show 3.11.0?

Comment: yes, i have the verbose output; no, `pyenv` was freshly installed with `curl https://pyenv.run | bash`; no

Comment: @Pablo is there anything else that may help? I suspect it may be a problem with the pi

Comment: hello @Tour I'm not sure. I did a quick research of similar problems and seems to be a hardware/storage issue but not sure. Sorry